# How can I tell if a bone property has a keyframe on the current frame using python?

Tags: python, animation

I need to be able to tell if a bone property has a keyframe on the current frame. I.e. the property box is yellow and not green.

I know you can evaluate an fcurve but how do you tell if it's a keyframe?
Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way, but you could extend the Object type by a method:

```
import bpy

def is_keyframe(ob, frame, data_path, array_index=-1):
    if ob is not None and ob.animation_data is not None and ob.animation_data.action is not None:
        for fcu in ob.animation_data.action.fcurves:
            if fcu.data_path == data_path:
                if array_index == -1 or fcu.array_index == array_index:
                    return frame in (p.co.x for p in fcu.keyframe_points)
    return False

bpy.types.Object.is_keyframe = is_keyframe    


# TEST
ob = bpy.context.object
pbone = bpy.context.active_pose_bone

# True or False 
ob.is_keyframe(20, pbone.path_from_id("location"), array_index=2)
```

`frame` can be int or float, `20` will match a `co.x` of `20.0`, but not a subframe like `20.1`. If you want to check for full frames, use `round(p.co.x)` in the `is_keyframe()` function.

Talked to ideasman_42, and he may check on adding a native method to retrieve F-Curve and Keyframe objects more easily.

Comment: Thank you, this looks awesome.
I will try and finish my addon before asking for additions to the API. Its a proof of concept for a new workflow, so it can be messy under the hood for now.